# Sharepoint 2013 Accordion Quick Launch

Tags: sharepoint, jquery-ui-accordion, quicklaunch

I want to add an accordion to my Quick Launch so I followed the tuto of Magali : [Link Accordion](http://sharingtothepoint.blogspot.ch/2013/10/how-to-make-accordion-menu-for-subsite.html)

Now I want to add collapse/expand image at the third level like this :

. Some Ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: probably you can hide/show image ... What you mean by collapse/expand image ?

Comment: I mean add + when it collapsed and - when it expanded in the third level parent of sharepoint Quick launch.